# How to run setq interactively

Tags: emacs, elisp, config

Specifically I want to do the same thing as `(setq frame-title-format ...)` would do in my config file, but from the `M-x` interactive command. `M-x setq` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Don't use `M-x`, use `M-:`, which runs the command [eval-expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html).

Answer (score 4):

To set a variable defined with `defcustom` you can also use `M-x set-variable`. You will not have to type the parentheses and you will have name completion.

Comment: `set-variable` only allows you to set user options, that is, variables whose documentation strings start with an asterisk character.

Comment: A user option is a variable defined by `defcustom`. I do not understand the asterisk character part of your comment.

Comment: The asterisk thing is an old convention, and it's not true anymore.

Comment: OK. That makes sense as I tried it and it did not work. Only defcustom does.

Comment: Yeah, I tried `M-x set-variable` for `frame-title-format` and it did not work: `[No match]`.

Comment: This is only for `defcustom` variables as mentioned in the answer. Since `frame-title-format` is not `defcustom`ed it cannot work.